# React Router with Next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-router, navigation, seo

I am thinking about using react router v6 with a Next 13 project I was wondering what are the down sides of using this configurations? I was looking into this and saw that this would affect SEO performance but I'm not sure of the extent it would affect SEO also I am not sure of any other downsides to this. I can't seem to find a lot about this and would love to hear what the community thinks.